# git repack error: "fsynch: Host is down"

Tags: git, nas

I am working with git, and the repository came to the point where an "automatic repacking" is needed to do git pull.

In the middle of that, git fails with error log:

```
Counting objects: 20727, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11473/11473), done.
fatal: fsync error on '.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_xPSRFZ': Host is down
error: failed to run repack
```

Has anyone have any idea of what this means(the error)?
The local repository is on a NAS disk, I am wondering if git using fsynch has any problem with NAS-storage based local repositories?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with git 1.9.1 that i was using.

I updated to the lastest git (2.2.2) with:
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade

And everything worked like a charm.